# SLURM not valid controller

Tags: slurm, hostname

in my master node the slurmctld is working, while in all other compute nodes fail with this error:

> slurmctld[1747]: slurmctld: error: This host (hostname/hostname) not a
> valid controller

The cluster apparently is working. Do you have any advice to understand what is and fix it?

Thanks

**PS.** some new info: the SLURM version installed in the master node is the same installed in the compute nodes. /etc/hosts file seems ok in all nodes. The hostname name reported in the "error" is the same reported in the node "hostname".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Slurm controller  (`slurmctld` service) should not run on the compute nodes, only on the management node(s).

The compute nodes must only run the `slurmd` service.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did the installation time ago and I do not remember ... I just added new nodes and I noticed this. Great!

Comment: I have been running slurmd as well as slurmctld (23.2.x) within the same container w/o any problems. So this is probably not the root cause.

Comment: Check, whether SlurmctldHost= directives have all a valid value, i.e. resolvable hostname set.